# Source for Climate Maps of Europe

Tags: europe, planning, weather-and-climate, maps

I'm planning a long trip to Europe and looking for maps of its climate during various months.  For example, a color map of average high temperatures over all of Europe (not just a particular city) in November.  I'm having trouble finding a good source for this.

As a bonus, I'd love to be able to visualize the average rainfall as well.

Comment: I did check out the suggestions there.  Some I had seen before. They both are happy to give you averages for a particular city but don't really give a feel for the region.  I could look up city by city, month by month but there must be a better way.  https://www.gate1travel.com/weather/europe/ is the best I've found so far but a visual version would be easier to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find something like that here: http://eca.knmi.nl/download/ensembles/ensembles.php

There's a registration button, and below that a link to access the data. I'm not sure what will happen if you fail to register, as there's no username/password prompt. You might just be able to go straight in to look at the data, I'm not sure. I've registered so I'm not sure if I could test that.

Anyway, from that you'll see a link below the registration button in the 'Already a Registered User?' section. From there you'll find a link labeled "Visualize Daily Maps" leading here: http://eca.knmi.nl/utils/mapserver/eobs_maps_registered.php

The map is daily, not monthly, but it has the visualizations you're looking for.

Comment: This is pretty cool.  It also has a link to the KNMI climate explorer which is much less pretty but will also do monthly time periods.